# How do you use Resources.Load?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have looked around for a while to fix this issue I'm having with loading sprites. I'm trying to load a sprite from folder Assets -> Resources -> Sprites -> Player, but it isn't, and I can't pinpoint the reason why? I have it loading in a static class, and trying to call it from another class, as it is a parameter in a struct I had made called Item.

[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIkee.png)

Item Struct

```cs
public string itemName;
    public string itemType;
    public int itemId;
    public Sprite itemSprite;
    public Color itemColour;

public Item(string ItemName, string ItemType, int ItemId, Sprite ItemSprite, Color ItemColour) {
    itemName = ItemName;
    itemType = ItemType;
    itemId = ItemId;
    itemSprite = ItemSprite;
    itemColour = ItemColour;
}
```

Static Class ItemDatabase

```cs
private static Item[] items = new Item[] {
new Item("Red Shirt" ,"Shirt", 0, Resources.Load("Sprites/Player/Base_3") as Sprite, new Color32(255, 0, 0, 255))
};

public static Item GetItemByID(int i) {
    return items[i];
}
```

Other Class

```cs
Debug.Log(ItemDatabase.GetItemByID(0).itemSprite);
```

It's returning null, and I have no idea why.

Comment: What is `GetItemByID` ?

Comment: Can you screenshot your folder structure too; Specifically is the path `Sprites/Player/Base_3` inside of `Assets/Resources` in unity?

Comment: Check the edits I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Its because its a sprite that is part of a bigger image asset

You need to do this:

```
Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites/Player/Base");
```

That will return an array with all of the sub-sprites in it and you can get "Base_3" using the third index. eg:

```
//do this once:
Sprite[] baseSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites/Player/Base");

//get the one you need:
return baseSprites[3];
```

Comment: This worked, didn't know you had to do that with these sorts of sprites, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how I found out either. But it has to do with the fact that the "subsprites" are just different metadata, not real objects. I suspect that they *might* be loadable individually by `Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Player/Base/Base_03");` but I've never tried. The one use I had for a sprite collection was for a bunch of icons, all of which I used everywhere.

Comment: Just tested it, you can't do `Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Player/Base/Base_3");` would be cool if you could, but oh well.